# Dynamically call a static variable (array)

Tags: php, class, static, model, methods

Here's my question for today. I'm building (for fun) a simple templating engine. The basic idea is that I have a tag like this {blog:content} and I break it in a method and a action. The problem is when I want to call a static variable dynamically, I get the following error .

```
Parse error: parse error, expecting `','' or `';''
```

And the code:

```
 $class = 'Blog';
 $action = 'content';
 echo $class::$template[$action];
```

$template is a public static variable(array) inside my class, and is the one I want to retreive.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What about [`get_class_vars`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-class-vars.php) ?

```
class Blog {
    public static $template = array('content' => 'doodle');
}

Blog::$template['content'] = 'bubble';

$class = 'Blog';
$action = 'content';
$values = get_class_vars($class);

echo $values['template'][$action];
```

Will output 'bubble'

Answer (score 5):

You may want to save a reference to the static array first.

```
class Test
{
    public static $foo = array('x' => 'y');
}

$class  = 'Test';
$action = 'x';

$arr = &$class::$foo;
echo $arr[$action];
```

Sorry for all the editing ...

**EDIT**

```
echo $class::$foo[$action];
```

Seems to work just fine in PHP 5.3. Ahh, "[Dynamic access to static methods is now possible](http://ch2.php.net/manual/en/migration53.new-features.php)" was added in PHP 5.3

Comment: Works fine in PHP 5.3. Let me check.

Comment: This is giving `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM`

Comment: That's nice, didn't know that.

Comment: It seems PHP 5.3 has some nice new features ( like this and NAMESPACE ).

Answer (score 0):

I'am not sure what i'm doing but give it a try:

```
echo eval( $class . "::" . $template[$action] );
```

Comment: Yep that should to the job. But I've forgot to mention eval is my last option :D .Not of fan of eval.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that without using [`eval()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php). `$class::$template`
 (even if it was valid syntax in PHP), would reference the static variable called `$template`, you would actually need [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) (`$class::$$template`), which is again not valid PHP syntax (you cannot access anything from a dynamic class name in PHP, IIRC).

I would recommend checking the variables for valid names before usng `eval()`, though (the regex is copied from the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php)):

```
if (!preg_match('[a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*', $class)) {
    throw new Exception('Invalid class name (' . $class . ')');
}
```

Comment: You're right, it seems Php is looking for $template . Thanks for the making this clear.

Comment: Yes, you can, you are right. I'll leave the answer for reference.

Answer (score 0):

As with everything in PHP, there are a lot of ways to skin the same cat. I believe the most efficient way to accomplish what you want is:

```
call_user_func(array($blog,$template));
```

See: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php