# Dynamically modify a static variable variable array

Tags: php, class, static, variable-variables

Similar to this question
[Dynamically call a static variable (array)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212171/dynamically-call-a-static-variable-array)
, but for writing to the variables.

I'm trying to initialize a couple static arrays in my constructor, but can't figure out how to code their names dynamically.

When I try this:

```
class MyClass {
    public static $something1 = array();
    public static $something2 = array();

    function __construct() {
        for( $i = 1; $i <= 2; $i++ ){
            $arr = "something{$dynamic}";
            self::$$arr[] = "a new element";
        }
    }
}
```

I get this error even if I don't call the constructor:

```
Fatal error: Cannot use [] for reading
```

Is there any way to accomplish this without using eval? I'm using PHP 5.4.

Comment: I don't know why you were downvoted. It wasn't me. For the record, your answer was correct: self::${$arr}[] = 'a new element';

Comment: No I meant, why did your question get downvoted?  I don't feel it should have.  Anyway I added my answer as an actual answer, below.

Comment: You bet.  Since you indicated my answer was correct please mark it as such by clicking the checkbox next to the up/down vote counter.

Comment: Had to wait for the timeout before I could mark it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
self::${$arr}[] = 'a new element';
```

The curly brackets provide the proper scope to the `$`