# Calling a PHP method from an Object the proper way

Tags: php, oop, object, methods

I am still learning OOP PHP and I keep swapping and changing between the following way of calling methods within an object

```
$obj = new Model();
$obj->method($param);
```

against

```
Model::method($params);
```

I understand the difference when I within the method as I can use $this in the first example, and I have to use self:: in the second.

Which is the correct way and what are the reasons of using each way

The reason I ask is I cannot find a suitable search term to research. I am currently reading a book on OOP and it will probably tell at some point, but would be nice to know now.

Comment: `$this` and `self` are not the same. `$this` is the instance whereas `self` is the class.

Comment: Consider being able to use `::method` on non-static methods a feature rather than something you're supposed to ever do.

Answer (score 2):

`Foo::bar()` calls the *static class method*, while `$foo->bar()` calls the *instance method* on an object. These are two completely different things. You do not need an object instance to call `Foo::bar()`, and in fact you do not have access to instance data when doing so. `Foo::bar()` is essentially nothing else but a regular function call like `bar()`, except that the function is attached to a class.

Instance methods act on a specific *object instance*:

```
class User {

    protected $name;

    public function __construct($name) {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function getName() {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public static function hi() {
        // no access to $this->name here, since static
        // methods are not bound to specific instances
        echo 'Hi';
    }

}

$dave = new User('Dave');
$mary = new User('Mary');

echo $dave->getName();  // Dave
echo $mary->getName();  // Mary

User::hi(); // Hi
```

Unless you understand *this*, you know nothing about OOP.

Comment: Yes I under stand the above, but wouldn't

Comment: No, it wouldn't. Uhm, what? ;-)

Comment: Sorry press enter ;)
So if the method requires properties contained in the class then it cannot be called statically, an instance needs to be made

Comment: Yes. `static` methods are always acting on the same data when called, if they're acting on data at all. *Instance methods* have access to the specific data of the object they're called on.

Comment: This may or may not be a little advanced, but try reading this: [How Not To Kill Your Testability Using Statics](http://kunststube.net/static/)

Comment: Great reading thanks. One more Question if you dont mind
class Test
{
  protected static $var = array(1=>'t',2=>'i',3=>'p')
}
do i call like 
Test::$var[1];

Comment: Ok found out on anther thread
[This Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212171/dynamically-call-a-static-variable-array)

Answer (score 1):

First example is a non-static call to the method, second a static call.
The first is better if you want to access private variables of your `Model`, second is better if you use the method like a normal function.
In general you should declare methods of the first type as static (`public static function method(){}`).

Answer (score 0):

First case is invocation of method on class instance, second case is call of static method.

See http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php

Answer (score 0):

There is no "proper" way because both call types serve different purposes.

The first call type is the standard way of handling objects: You initialize a concrete instance of a class. This instance can have its own internal values and each instance can use these values to create a different result when you call the method with the same parameter.

The second call type is called static and operates directly on the class, there is no instance (hence no `$this`). There are some use cases for it, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2671496/java-when-to-use-static-methods) for Java, it's the same for PHP.